# How the search filter from search bar works in mern?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, search, filtering, mern

I have a common search bar to search products on every page , so how to search products on the backend using the search words. like in e-commerce sites if we search black shoes , we get all products related to black shoes even if the listed products' names do not have the terms 'black' , 'shoes'?